# Testing batches of hard drives

Tags: hard-drive

I've gotten a hold of a bunch of old sata hard drives (around 10 or so) but I have no idea if they're working or not.

Is there an efficient way to test all these, rather than powering off, opening my case, installing the drive, and booting for each one?

So far the only solution I could come up with is to buy some sort of enclosure that lets me hook each drive up via USB, but I was wondering if there were any other ways to do it.

Comment: For me the most efficient (quickest, cheapest) way to do this would be to use the *non-enclosed* SATA to USB adapter I already have. For others the most efficient way might be to hit each one with a large sledgehammer until it's state can be visually determined. You might measure efficiency differently to me though.

Comment: I'd recommend a USB 3.0 docking station, such as [this one](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00001642) for example.

Comment: You could install several of them at the same time (e.g. two batches of 5) rather than installing and testing them onbe by one.  But the easiest way is indeed an external docking station. Connect that directly to your eSATA or USB port.

Comment: i'd install as many of them in your machine as possible, preferably a spare machine.  then, run some sort of disk reinitialization software on each drive.  When I tested my new 5TB  drives, it took about 36-48 hours, but once it was complete i was confident that i had not received any bad drives.  reinitialization tests every single sector

Comment: If your system is on AHCI you can - but only reasonably safely - hot-plugging the drives to the desktop you have. Sata is designed as hot-swap-compatible. But those are old drives, status unknown, you never now if connected one overloads +5V line or crash system due to internal mechanical fault

I would go for an USB stand, personally, just like @Karan suggests.